# How to make an excel sheet into a png using python without win32 library

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to export a whole excel sheet that contains charts and table into a png using Python. I need to get this done without the win32 library because it will be deployed to Linux.

I tried aspose cells but that causes the image to have a water mark. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm dubious that this is possible at all.  You can use `openpyxl` to add charts to an xlsx file, but that's not going to render them.  Rendering them requires the Excel application.  Remember that the xlsx file does not contain the images.  It just contains the description of the chart.  You can try using LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Aspose.Cells for Python can render spreadsheet to PNG. You found output images are watermarked. This is due to the fact that you are using Aspose.Cells for Python in evaluation mode (without a valid license  to be set in code). If you purchase the API, then you may specify the license in code at the start of your program and it won't add watermark to the images or files.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.